# Count times digits appear in a number C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while, digits

I am trying to make a code in C that takes a number as an input, counts how many times 0-9 appears in the given number.
The code as nooby as it might is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num,dig,dat[9],mod;

    printf("Give a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    mod = num % 10;


  while(mod != 0)
    {

      if(mod > 1)
      {
          dig = mod / 10;

          while(dig >= 0 )
          {
              ++dat[dig];

          }
      }
      else if(mod =1)
      {
          dig = mod/1;

           while(dig >= 0 )
          {
              ++dat[dig];

          }

      }
      --mod;

    }
      printf("%d appears %d\n",dig,dat[dig]);


    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Nothing really works, i dont even get any response from printf.

Comment: Very suspicious statement: `if(mod =1)`

Comment: Don't assume that a "number" is an integer. It is easier to solve as a string.

Comment: Array is too short: `dat[9]` should be `dat[10]`. It's also uninitialised.

Comment: Your inner `while` loops are infinite loops since the control variable `dig` does not change.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n = 12334268;
    int digits[10] = {0};
    
    while(n)
    {
        ++digits[n%10];
        n/=10;
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        if (digits[i])
        {
            printf("Digit %d appears %d times\n", i, digits[i]);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5512KB
Digit 1 appears 1 times
Digit 2 appears 2 times
Digit 3 appears 2 times
Digit 4 appears 1 times
Digit 6 appears 1 times
Digit 8 appears 1 times
```

Comment: thanks, what does the line "++digits[n%10];" help with? (im a noob)

Comment: Very nice. Just a minor point: a do while loop (a bottom-tested loop) is probably a better choice here to guarantee at least one pass through the loop and therefore properly handle an entry of just 0.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the array `dat` shall have `10` elements because there are `10` digits `0-9`.

```
dat[10],
```

And moreover you are using the uninitialized array

```
++dat[dig];
```

If the entered number is divisible by `10` then the while loop is skipped

```
mod = num % 10;


while(mod != 0)
{
   //...
```

So the code does not make sense.

Pay attention to that you should deal with unsigned integers. Otherwise the program shall take into account the sign of the entered number.

Also the user can enter `0` that is a valid number containing one digit `0`.

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    unsigned int digits[N] = { 0 };

    unsigned int num;

    printf( "Give a number: " );

    if ( scanf( "%u",&num ) == 1 )
    {
        const unsigned int Base = 10;
        do
        {
            ++digits[num % Base];
        } while ( num /= Base );

        puts( "The number contains the following digits:" );
        for ( unsigned int i = 0, j = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            if ( digits[i] != 0 )
            {
                if ( j != 0 ) printf( ", " );
                printf( "%u: %u", i, digits[i] );
                j = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```